# How do multiple date queries differ between Craft 2 and 3

Tags: datetime, conditional, query

After spending a lot of time solving this for myself I thought I'd share it.
In my Craft 2 template I had this query:

```
{% set result = craft.entries({
    section: 'events',
    eventDate: ['and', '<' ~ now.w3c(), '> ' ~ now | date_modify('-6 days')],
    results: ':notempty:',
    order: 'eventDate desc',
    with: ['imageGallery'],
    limit: 3
}) %}
```

Answer (score 3):

My Craft 3 version is:

```
{% set result = craft.entries()
    .section('events')
    .eventDate( ['and', '<' ~ now|atom, '>' ~ now|date_modify('-6 days')|atom ] )
    .results(':notempty:')
    .orderBy('eventDate desc')
    .limit(3)
    .with(['imageGallery'])
    .all()
%}
```

Note the extra `|atom` after the `date_modify('-6 days')`

Comment: The [atom](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/filters.html#atom) filter would work too, so just simplified your example to use that. Also worth noting that [batch-setting parameters](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/#setting-parameters) is still supported, though the chain syntax you’ve switched to is better (gives the query a chance to do normalization on the values).

Comment: I seem to remember being advised to use the batch setting method in preference in a past SE answer. This caused me some confusion switching my existing Craft 2 code to Craft 3 as all the example code uses the chain syntax.

Comment: It was faster to use the batch method in Craft 2; in Craft 3 it’s a wash either way.